# How to use IF ELSE in JOIN condition (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have given the pseudo code below for JOIN condition. Please can you help me on how to write the SQL.

```
IF (left.detail_valid_to_date = NULL)
         WHERE left.right_address_entry_id = right.address_entry_id AND 
               right.detail_valid_to_date = NULL
   IF (left.detail_valid_to_date <> NULL)
         WHERE left.right_address_entry_id = right.address_entry_id 
               AND right.detail_valid_from_date <= left.detail_valid_to_date 
               AND left.detail_valid_to_date <= right.detail_valid_to_date
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: `WHERE (left.detail_valid_to_date is NULL AND left.right_address_entry_id = right.address_entry_id AND 
               right.detail_valid_to_date is NULL) OR (NOT(left.detail_valid_to_date is NULL) AND left.right_address_entry_id = right.address_entry_id 
               AND right.detail_valid_from_date <= left.detail_valid_to_date 
               AND left.detail_valid_to_date <= right.detail_valid_to_date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   select * from 
   lefttable l inner join righttable r
   on l.right_address_entry_id = r.address_entry_id 
   where (l.detail_valid_to_date = NULL and r.detail_valid_to_date = NULL)
   or (l.detail_valid_to_date <> NULL and r.detail_valid_from_date <= l.detail_valid_to_date AND l.detail_valid_to_date <= r.detail_valid_to_date)
```

Comment: Cheers! You deserve a upvote too. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I cant really test this without an example but I think since you are doing the same join in either case. You can combine your if statements into a single WHERE clause like so.

```
FROM right    
    JOIN left ON  left.right_address_entry_id = right.address_entry_id
WHERE (left.detail_valid_to_date is null 
       and right.detail_valid_to_date is null) or (left.detail_valid_to_date <> NULL
                                                   and right.detail_valid_from_date <= left.detail_valid_to_date 
                                                   and left.detail_valid_to_date <= right.detail_valid_to_date)
```